# AdMob for Android: AppStreamingHelper(27173): No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, admob

I'm trying to get Admob running in my Game ( C++ / NDK / SDLActivity / Eclipse / Android-API19 / Google-Play-Services ) and get following error in the logcat: "AppStreamingHelper(27173): No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0."

What am I missing ?

Here a more detailed foregoing excerpt from logcat:

```
    07-04 13:35:00.730: V/Mw(20836): java_requestNewInterstitial: loading Ad.
    07-04 13:35:00.760: I/dalvikvm(20836): Could not find method android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy.getInstance, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.state.h.a
    07-04 13:35:00.760: W/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: unable to resolve static method 1390: Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;.getInstance ()Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;
    07-04 13:35:00.760: D/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0072
    07-04 13:35:00.770: I/dalvikvm(20836): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method gsk.a
    07-04 13:35:00.770: W/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 799: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
    07-04 13:35:00.770: D/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001e
    07-04 13:35:00.790: I/dalvikvm(20836): Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method gsi.a
    07-04 13:35:00.790: W/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 527: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
    07-04 13:35:00.790: D/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00f4
    07-04 13:35:00.800: D/ChimeraCfgMgr(20836): Reading stored module config
    07-04 13:35:00.840: D/dalvikvm(20836): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
    07-04 13:35:00.840: W/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: unable to resolve static field 304 (SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
    07-04 13:35:00.840: D/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0012
    07-04 13:35:00.840: D/dalvikvm(20836): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS
    07-04 13:35:00.840: W/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: unable to resolve static field 303 (SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
    07-04 13:35:00.840: D/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0021
    07-04 13:35:00.840: D/dalvikvm(20836): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
    07-04 13:35:00.840: W/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: unable to resolve static field 304 (SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
    07-04 13:35:00.840: D/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0008
    07-04 13:35:00.840: D/dalvikvm(20836): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_ABIS
    07-04 13:35:00.840: W/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: unable to resolve static field 305 (SUPPORTED_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
    07-04 13:35:00.840: D/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0008
    07-04 13:35:00.850: D/dalvikvm(20836): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
    07-04 13:35:00.850: I/dalvikvm(20836): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0130 at 0x17 in Lcom/google/android/chimera/container/FileApkUtils;.getSupportedAbisForCurrentRuntime
    07-04 13:35:00.850: D/dalvikvm(20836): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS
    07-04 13:35:00.850: I/dalvikvm(20836): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x012f at 0x26 in Lcom/google/android/chimera/container/FileApkUtils;.getSupportedAbisForCurrentRuntime
    07-04 13:35:00.850: D/dalvikvm(20836): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
    07-04 13:35:00.850: I/dalvikvm(20836): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0130 at 0x0d in Lcom/google/android/chimera/container/FileApkUtils;.is64BitRuntime
    07-04 13:35:00.850: D/ChimeraFileApk(20836): Primary ABI of requesting process is armeabi-v7a
    07-04 13:35:00.850: D/ChimeraFileApk(20836): Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
    07-04 13:35:00.850: I/dalvikvm(20836): Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getColor, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.ModuleResources.getColor
    07-04 13:35:00.850: W/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 823: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getColor (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)I
    07-04 13:35:00.850: D/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
    07-04 13:35:00.850: I/dalvikvm(20836): Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getColor, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.ModuleResources.getColor
    07-04 13:35:00.850: W/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 823: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getColor (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)I
    07-04 13:35:00.850: D/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000d
    07-04 13:35:00.850: I/dalvikvm(20836): Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getColorStateList, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.ModuleResources.getColorStateList
    07-04 13:35:00.850: W/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 825: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getColorStateList (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
    07-04 13:35:00.850: D/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
    07-04 13:35:00.850: I/dalvikvm(20836): Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getColorStateList, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.ModuleResources.getColorStateList
    07-04 13:35:00.850: W/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 825: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getColorStateList (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
    07-04 13:35:00.850: D/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000d
    07-04 13:35:00.850: I/dalvikvm(20836): Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.ModuleResources.getDrawable
    07-04 13:35:00.850: W/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 832: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    07-04 13:35:00.850: D/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
    07-04 13:35:00.850: I/dalvikvm(20836): Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.ModuleResources.getDrawable
    07-04 13:35:00.850: W/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 832: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    07-04 13:35:00.850: D/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000d
    07-04 13:35:00.850: I/dalvikvm(20836): Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.ModuleResources.getDrawableForDensity
    07-04 13:35:00.850: W/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 834: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    07-04 13:35:00.850: D/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
    07-04 13:35:00.850: I/dalvikvm(20836): Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.ModuleResources.getDrawableForDensity
    07-04 13:35:00.850: W/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 834: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    07-04 13:35:00.850: D/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000d
    07-04 13:35:00.860: D/DynamitePackage(20836): Instantiated singleton DynamitePackage.
    07-04 13:35:00.860: D/DynamitePackage(20836): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
    07-04 13:35:00.870: I/dalvikvm(20836): Could not find method android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy.getInstance, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.state.h.a
    07-04 13:35:00.870: W/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: unable to resolve static method 1764: Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;.getInstance ()Landroid/security/NetworkSecurityPolicy;
    07-04 13:35:00.870: D/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0072
    07-04 13:35:00.880: I/dalvikvm(20836): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method ahs.a
    07-04 13:35:00.880: W/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1337: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
    07-04 13:35:00.880: D/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001e
    07-04 13:35:00.880: D/dalvikvm(20836): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lmb;.common_google_play_services_unknown_issue
    07-04 13:35:00.880: W/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: unable to resolve static field 4781 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lmb;
    07-04 13:35:00.880: D/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0012
    07-04 13:35:00.900: V/WebViewChromium(20836): Binding Chromium to the main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {420aaef8}
    07-04 13:35:00.900: I/chromium(20836): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
    07-04 13:35:00.900: I/BrowserProcessMain(20836): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
    07-04 13:35:00.910: D/dalvikvm(20836): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lmb;.common_google_play_services_updating_text
    07-04 13:35:00.910: W/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: unable to resolve static field 4787 (common_google_play_services_updating_text) in Lmb;
    07-04 13:35:00.910: D/dalvikvm(20836): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0021
    07-04 13:35:00.910: D/dalvikvm(20836): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lmb;.common_google_play_services_updating_title
    07-04 13:35:00.910: I/dalvikvm(20836): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x12b4 at 0x2e in Lot;.a
    07-04 13:35:00.920: W/chromium(20836): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
    07-04 13:35:00.930: I/Adreno-EGL(20836): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8960_KK_2.7_RB1__release_AU ()
    07-04 13:35:00.930: I/Adreno-EGL(20836): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.12.SPL
    07-04 13:35:00.930: I/Adreno-EGL(20836): Build Date: 03/25/14 Tue
    07-04 13:35:00.930: I/Adreno-EGL(20836): Local Branch: 
    07-04 13:35:00.930: I/Adreno-EGL(20836): Remote Branch: quic/kk_2.7_rb1.32
    07-04 13:35:00.930: I/Adreno-EGL(20836): Local Patches: NONE
    07-04 13:35:00.930: I/Adreno-EGL(20836): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
    07-04 13:35:01.060: I/Ads(20836): Starting ad request.
    07-04 13:35:01.070: D/AppStreamingHelper(20836): Creating delegate
    07-04 13:35:01.070: W/DynamiteLoaderImpl(20836): Failed to load module version: module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found
    07-04 13:35:01.070: D/GmsModuleFndr(20836): Staging file APK's and updating chimera config...
    07-04 13:35:01.190: D/GmsModuleFndr(20836): Staging file APKs completed
    07-04 13:35:01.190: W/DynamiteLoaderImpl(20836): Failed to load module version after staging: module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found
    07-04 13:35:01.190: W/DynamiteModule(20836): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite not found.
    07-04 13:35:01.190: I/DynamiteModule(20836): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:0
    07-04 13:35:01.190: E/AppStreamingHelper(20836): No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
    07-04 13:35:01.240: V/Mw(20836): java_requestNewInterstitial: adRequest: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest@420f2f90
    07-04 13:35:01.240: V/Mw(20836): java_requestNewInterstitial: end.
    07-04 13:35:01.240: V/Mw(20836): java_onCreate: Ad wasn't loaded.
```